# Syntax error when using `get` in object property shorthand

Tags: javascript, v8, ecmascript-6

This bit of code:

```
function get() {
  console.log('get')
}

var obj = {
  get
}

obj.get()
```

results in a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` in iojs and Chrom{ium,e} but works fine in Firefox.

Longhand, of course, works fine:

```
function get() {
  console.log('get')
}

var obj = {
  get: get
}

obj.get()
```

So does using a word other than `get`

```
function git() {
  console.log('get')
}

var obj = {
  git
}

obj.git()
```

Is this a bug in V8 or something else? What am I not *get*ting here?

Comment: Your `obj` in the first case is not a valid Java script object. The `get` is not bound to a `property` or an `expression`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: not until ES6 can you use shorthand object property assignment `{x}` in literals, in ES5, you need to use long-hand `{x:x}`

Comment: Are you sure the 3rd example works in Chrome?  When I look at the browser compatibility for shorthand property names [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) says this is (for the moment) only supported in FF.

Comment: @sfletche It works on Chrome 45.0.2438.3 dev and iojs-v2.0.1 to v2.3.4 for me.

Comment: Not sure why AmmarCSE deleted their answer, but I believe it's correct: Chrome expects a getter.

Comment: Does it change when you switch from sloppy to strict mode?

Answer (score 3):

v8 hasn't made this available by default yet<sup>1</sup>; firefox (which doesn't use v8) has.

For now, you can transpile with [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#enhanced-object-literals).

<sup>1</sup> It's available, but not in every runtime environment. In node.js, for example, you need to enable it with a `--harmony_something` flag.

Comment: The third example works for me in Chrome 45.0.2438.3 dev and iojs-v2.0.1 to v2.3.4 though, it's just the `get` word that doesn't.

Comment: @dido I think the new object literal syntax doesn't work with `get` because the parser treats it as the reserved word (along with `set`) used for defining getters. However, that doesn't explain why your example works in FF but not chrome.

Comment: @dido get and set are used for the es5 object literal accessor syntax